# How to format minutes/seconds with Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, format

I want to take the time that some operations need; so I wrote:

```
def get_formatted_delta(start_time):
    seconds = ( datetime.datetime.now() - start_time ).total_seconds()
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    min = '{:02.0f}'.format(m)
    sec = '{:02.4f}'.format(s)
    return '{} minute(s) {} seconds'.format(min, sec)
```

but when I run that; I get printouts like:

00 minute(s) 1.0010 seconds

Meaning: as expected, 0 minutes are showing up as "00".
But 1 seconds shows up as 1.xxxx - instead of 01.xxxx

So, what is wrong with my format specification?

Comment: @MartijnPeters beat me to it. On a side note, try not to hide predefined functions (like `min`) with your identifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field width applies to the *whole field* including the decimals and the decimal point. For 4 decimals plus the point, plus 2 places for the integer portion, you need 7 characters:

```
>>> format(1.001, '07.4f')
'01.0010'
```

You don't need to format those floats separately, you can do all formatting and interpolation in one step:

```
def get_formatted_delta(start_time):
    seconds = ( datetime.datetime.now() - start_time ).total_seconds()
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return '{:02.0f} minute(s) {:07.4f} seconds'.format(m, s)
```

Comment: So, why did he get `1.0010` from `02.4f`? The number of decimals takes precedence over the field width specifier?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: because the width is the *minimal* field width. `02` means: pad out the result of the format with zeros on the left if the output is shorter than 2 characters. The `.4` part guarantees that the field width is going to be 6 characters at least, so the padding never takes place.